# How can i convert this to a factory/abstract factory?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, migradoc

I'm using [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MigraDocOverview.ashx) to create a pdf document.

I have business entities similar to the those used in [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MigraDocOverview.ashx).

```
    public class Page{
      public List<PageContent> Content { get; set; } 
    }


  public abstract class PageContent {

        public int Width { get; set; }      
        public int Height { get; set; } 
        public Margin Margin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paragraph : PageContent{
         public string Text { get; set; }    
    }

    public class Table : PageContent{
         public int Rows { get; set; }    
         public int Columns { get; set; }  
        //.... more
    }
```

In my business logic, there are rendering classes for each type

```
public interface IPdfRenderer<T>
{
    T Render(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section s);
} 

class ParagraphRenderer
    : IPdfRenderer<MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Paragraph>
{
    BusinessEntities.PDF.Paragraph paragraph;

    public ParagraphRenderer(BusinessEntities.PDF.Paragraph p)
    {
     paragraph = p;
    }

    public MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Paragraph Render(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section s)
    {
        var paragraph = s.AddParagraph(); // add text from paragraph etc
        return paragraph;
    }
}


public class TableRenderer : IPdfRenderer<MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table>
{
    BusinessEntities.PDF.Table table;
    public TableRenderer(BusinessEntities.PDF.Table t)
    {
        table =t;
    }
    public MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table Render(Section obj)
    {
        var table = obj.AddTable();
        //fill table based on table
    }
}
```

I want to create a PDF page as :

```
            var document = new Document();
            var section = document.AddSection();// section is a page in pdf
            var page = GetPage(1); // get a page from business classes
            foreach (var content in page.Content)
            {
                      //var renderer = createRenderer(content); //
                     // get Renderer based on Business type ??
                     // renderer.Render(section) 
            }
```

For createRenderer() i can use switch case/dictionary and return type.

**How can i get/create the renderer generically based on type ?**

How can I use factory or abstract factory here?

Or which design pattern better suits this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a factory where your key would  be the type, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/669631/Better-factories-in-Csharp) article has some examples.

If you can afford to use IoC, is better if you let IoC engine decide which concrete class should be used based on a string, you should configure your containers accordingly. This string can be Type name.
I suggest [ninject](http://www.ninject.org) but any other IoC like windsor can work.

Below is an example of how can be done using a factory with generic interfaces, since in your case there is contructor you need to pass is it.

```
public class Factory<T>
{
    public Factory()
    {
        _Mappings = new Dictionary<string,Func<IInterface<T>>>(2);

        _Mappings.Add("MyClass1", () => new MyClass1() as IInterface<T>);
        _Mappings.Add("MyClass2", () => new MyClass2() as IInterface<T>);
    }
    public IInterface<T> Get(string typeName)
    {
        Func<IInterface<T>> func;
        if (_Mappings.TryGetValue(typeName, out func))
        {
            return func();
        }
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IInterface<T>>> _Mappings;
}

public class MyClass1 : IInterface<int>
{
    public int Method()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : IInterface<string>
{
    public string Method()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IInterface<T>
{
    T Method();
}
```

I still think IoC is better, but this is a valid approach.

Comment: pls can you explain more? I'm not able to map the article to  my situation.

Comment: Below is an example of a factory using same concept but using type name as a key. You should replace my generic interface with your generic interface. You need to pass an extra paremeter in factory get to populate your constructor.

Comment: public class Factory<T>
    {
        public Factory()
        {
            _Mappings = new Dictionary<string,Func<IInterface<T>>>(2);
            
            _Mappings.Add("MyClass1", () => new MyClass1() as IInterface<T>);
            _Mappings.Add("MyClass2", () => new MyClass2() as IInterface<T>);
        }

Comment: I tried to copy the code and is too long, I tried to split it in chunks and complained that only 1 comment each 15 seconds, I give up. If you mention your email I can provide details.

Comment: I modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your interface definition can be enhanced. Instead just returning the generic and accepting input as constructor, you can do both accepting the generic as input and return it as well.

```
public interface IPdfRenderer<T>
{
    T Render(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section s, T baseContent);
}
```

Then expanding arutromonriv's answer,

```
public class DynamicRenderer : IPdfRenderer<PageContent>
{
    public DynamicRenderer(IPdfRenderer<Paragraph> paragraph
        , IPdfRenderer<Table> table){
        //variable assignment
    }
    public PageContent Render(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Section s, PageContent baseContent){
        if(baseContent is Paragraph){ return paragraph.Render(s, baseContent as Paragraph); }
        else{ return table.Render(s, baseContent as Table); }
    }
}
```

With this you can do:

```
var renderer = createRenderer(); //
foreach (PageContent content in page.Content)
{
    // get Renderer based on Business type ??
    renderer.Render(section, content);
}
```